# PHP 5.3 vs PHP 5.2 - need reflection?

Tags: php, php-5.3, php-5.2

Think I need to use reflection to make this 5.3 code work on 5.2 but having issues.

We are on a server that only has PHP 5.2, upgrade is not possible at this time per hosting company but a class we need has issues on 5.2 since the class uses 5.3 syntax.

Here is the code I need help with:

```
static public function instance($class) {
    if (!isset($class::$instance)) {
        $class::$instance = new $class();
        $class::$instance->initialize();

        MobileHelper::registerDevice($class::$instance);
    }

    return $class::$instance;
}
```

I have seen a number of answers on questions that note to use reflection, but they are all basic examples, I don't know enough to convert them into the solution here, but I have tried.  Any expert here able to help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Here, same using Reflection.

```
static public function instance($class) {
    $ref = new ReflectionClass($class);
    if (!$ref->getStaticPropertyValue('instance')){
        $ref->setStaticPropertyValue('instance', new $class());
        $obj = $ref->getStaticPropertyValue('instance');
        $obj->initialize();
        MobileHelper::registerDevice($obj);
    }
    return $ref->getStaticPropertyValue('instance');
}
```